# How to exclude null records when using Image::where('category_id', $imageCategoryId)?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all images which have category_id of $imageCategoryId, however, since having a category is not mandatory an image might have a category of NULL.

My code takes the category of the current image and returns all images with the same category, however, if the category of the image is NULL it returns all other images with a category of NULL instead of no images.

This is why I'm trying to exclude NULL records from my search.

```
$image = Image::find($id);
$imageCategoryId = $image->category_id;
$similarImages = Image::where('category_id', $imageCategoryId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
```

Comment: Did you tried using Eloquent relationships ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Using `whereRaw` method:

You can use `whereRaw` to perform that.

**Example**:

```
$similarImages = Image::whereRaw("category_id = '$imageCategoryId' AND category_id != '' ")->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
```

## Using the `where` method multiple times:

Or you can also use the `where` method multiple times and it will act, like an `AND` statement like in the example below:

```
$similarImages = Image::where("category_id","=",$imageCategoryId)->where("category_id","!=",'')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
```

For more information visit the [Laravel 5.7 WHERE CLAUSE Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

You could do just this:

```
$similarImages = $imageCategoryId ? Image::where('category_id', $imageCategoryId)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get() : [];
```

Comment: Is there a way to exclude them in the query instead of using what you've used ( I think it's ternary operator )

Answer (score 0):

You could use whereNotNull

```
$similarImages = Image::where('category_id', $imageCategoryId)->whereNotNull('category_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(9)->get();
```